# Need to search a big file of integers using Java

Tags: java, file, search, memory

I have a file which has 100,000 lines and each line is a list of space separated 1000 integers(ranging from 0 to 1,000,000). Now I need to to make an API which when given two inputs a and b tells me if there are two numbers present in same line in file where b comes after a in terms of index. Total size of file is ~700 MB.

Since it is an API I cannot read every time from file by creating a stream, as I have to take care of response time and disk reads are slow. And I cannot load everything in memory since the file is too big.

Any suggestions on what is an optimal way?

Note - I created an API by loading everything to memory and making a hashmap of number -> set of line it belongs and then tried to search it. It works for smaller files, but when I try to start the server with larger file , the server does not starts(I am new to JAVA too, can anyone help me on where to see the logs on why it is not starting?. I am just doing java -jar $DIR/target/test.jar in my bash script)

Comment: 700 MB is too big?

Comment: What error does it given when the server does not start?  If it is an message that it is out of memory, you can probably just assign it more memory to solve the issue, unless you foresee these files will get even larger (say more than a couple of GB).

Comment: I assume the upper bound is one million. Uneven comma grouping is an India-only quirk, and I'm editing to reflect standard usage.

Comment: Also, a HashMap with 2 Integer objects for keys and values is not very optimal for memory use.  You may want to look into using a native java collections that uses standard ints instead of objects: https://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html, however that is a bit of an advanced topic.

Comment: @john16384 Even 7 MB is pretty big if the programmatic approach was small, indecent and poorly handled

Comment: I am just running this on my local machine. I know its not such a big file, but server is just not starting when I am trying to load the big file, process it and store it in memory. I would have used redis in production environment, but if I cannot do that, then any suggestion on what can I do? Or why server is not starting(where are logs generated? I am using HttpServer.create to start server)? I am a python guy and is a bit out of touch in Java. Any help would be of great help.

Comment: @Rishabh You may wanna share some code and a small reflection(atleast some content) of the original file, so that people here could really help your case

Comment: @Rishabh If you can handle this problem in Python first, then you will have a nice way of knowing how java could have handled the same

Comment: @ShayHaned - Can you atleast please help me on where I can see the error logs on why server is not starting? I guess rest I will be able to figure out. But I am using HttpServer.create of Java to start the server. I am using java -jar $DIR/target/test.jar in my bash file to run my code. Built the project using Maven. Any insights onto this?

Comment: @Rishabh Ok, look since it's not really matter where you are facing OutOfMemoryException because of **so-called big file reads** , you should really expose the original code that you are using regarding the HttpServer class and your whole connection setup deal for handling the server-client communication

Comment: @john16384 - I am not sure if using the other data structure will help in this case. My main problem is that I am not able to see why server is not starting on my local machine with big file(Probably memory leakage). I am embarrassed, but I have touched Java after span of 6 years and am struggling for basics. Also please don't hit me for this, but once my server starts, data in between API calls won't persist in memory in Java too right?(I know this is language independent concept, but I am just being shameless in asking.)

Comment: @chrylis - thank you for edit. And yes it crosses 1 million, if that is the upper bound.

Comment: @Rishabh there is also no shame in atleast posting the code you have regarding this problem :)

Comment: @ShayHaned - I was figuring out how to post it in formatted manner in comments. But for starting server all I am doing is : 
HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8088), 0);

httpServer.createContext("/api/direct", new RouteRegistryHandler(registry));
httpServer.start();

Comment: @Rishabh , Ok, so when you execute this code, do you get any errors like, ConnectTimeout or **your code is failing anyway** kind of errors??

Comment: @ShayHaned - As I said I am using a bash script to start the server. bash test.sh start and internally I am doing java -jar $DIR/target/test.jar in maven built project. And I am not getting error upfront while running this script. That is what i want where can I see the error logs in this case?

Comment: @Rishabh I can understand a little part of your problem now, but you must realize that all this had nothing to do with the actual problem **file size and all**, and after **HttpServer.create**, you will need to know how to manage the communication process using **HttpHandler** right? So that you could init **input and output streams** for both client and server side? So that changes the nature of your entire question. Posting it again might be beneficial with all the problems that you are actually facing

Comment: How often does the contents of the data set change? If it is stable, you can solve most of your problems by storing the numbers in a database table with columns (`line`, `index`, `number`). Then, come up with an SQL query that selects the lines where `b` appears after `a`. Use Java to dispatch requests and communicate responses.

Comment: @SinanÜnür - Thank you from your input. But I cannot use a database here, else I would have done that in first place.

Comment: Not even SQLite?

Comment: No Sinan. That is what the problem is. It has to be read from a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you have a lot of numbers (100M) and if you want to keep them all in memory you should prepare to use Gbs of ram. Good news is that highest number is 1M, thus making a lot of numbers repeating.

I would probably represent the file with a graph. Each node contains a number (1-1000000) so you have 1 million nodes, fast indexed for O(1) access (nodes could be easily implemented as cell of array). Then each node X is connected to a node Y if Y appear at right of X in any line of the file.

Solution involves finding a connectivity of two nodes in the graph. I'm not an expert here, and I would implement a dfs like algorithm paying attention to avoid cycles. Due to this avoiding, finding algorithm will touch at max 1 million nodes, making complexity low.

About space: each line should produce 999 connections, that is (multiplied by 100k lines) = almost 100 million connections. If each connection is 4 bytes (but you can improve as all you need is 20 bit to store 1 million) then you have 400Mb of memory for connections.

So with 400Mb of ram you can make your API answer very fast.

Comment: First of all thanks for your valuable input. I would have done the same, but the problem is that the data resides in file. For creating the graph itself you will need a lot of time. This solution can only be considered optimized if you preload the graph somewhere in memory(maybe redis or some graph DB like neo4js). But since I have to read it from file(that is the constraint), this solution probably wont work. Infact if preloading was allowed, I could have just created a hash where  key is one of the number(1-1000000),& value is a set containing all the lines where this number lies.

Comment: Wait - you stated you tried with no success to preload, not that it wasn't allowed. If it is allowed you should do it: no matter how much time it takes initialization (Also consider to save the graph struct once built as replacement of input file for further faster preloads). Solution you proposed (hashmap of number->#lines) has an higher memory consumption, and this could have led to preload failure you stated in your original post.

Comment: Just a comment on solution you tried: using a HashMap for numbers 1-1M is not optimal as having an index based array (so that space is n and access really 1). The same for Set as value, as you will use this as list. Besides that, even if you use array instead of map/set (and optimizing space), you still will need to read file after the index lookup; that's still inefficient.

Comment: Jack, I won't need to read file after index lookup, if I already have the mapping in memory. And creating the graph and saving that construct will also take same amount of memory(nodes and edges both). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry but it was you who set strict constraints "cannot read every time from file" and "cannot load everything in memory". Let's have a coherent debate. If you have no memory limit ideal is to use a 1Mx1M bit map (15Gb of ram). If you have limits than deal with them coherently. Don't want to read file? use a graph. You have large enough memory but not huge? Hold a map <number>-<list of [line-number][position]> (Mid space, Very fast). Can hold file in memory or can read it? Line indexing is fine. Is it optimal? probably not.